# What does ように mean here?

Tags: meaning

So person A is talking to person B.

A is saying he will move, B asks when, and A responds "tomorrow", and after that he adds the following sentence:

> ここに来るようになったぐらいだったかな、決まったの。

I guess it roughly means "It has been decided around the time since I started coming here."

I want to know what the ように means in this case.

ように means:

> in order to / so that / hoping or wishing for something

However I can't really fit in these meanings with this sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have correctly guessed, `dictionary-form + ようになる` means "(gradually) come to ～", "learn to ～", "start to ～", etc. You can find many examples [on JGram](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=youninaru) and [on ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B). よう (様 in kanji) is a word which has many meanings including *style/manner*, *status*, *way/method* or *appearance*. ～ようになる may be interpreted as something like "become a status of doing ～", but it's better to memorize this pattern as-is.

The sentence says "As I recall, it was when I *started to* come here that it was decided."